# CTS execution using junit categories

Tags: android, junit4, cts

CTS execution:

How can we trigger the test suite of Junit by using annotations and categories through command line?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can run CTS individual test methods or the whole class using android instrumentation command.

For Example: Here in this example CTS test class with a specific method is mentioned to run, you can remove the test method from the below command to run all test methods within the class.

adb shell am instrument -w -e class android.animation.AnimatorSetEventsTest#testCancel 
    \com.android.frameworks.coretests android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

For more details on running tests via instrumentation follow this link - 
https://source.android.com/compatibility/tests/development/instrumentation